# Win API - Delete all files except some

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, delete-file

Consider I want to write a program that delete all files in a given directory, except for few files which the user can define to preserve (by using a config file for example).
Is there a native way to do it? The direct approach is to loop over all the files and to decide for each of them if to call `DeleteFile` or not. But is it the right approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Write your own code to loop over the files

Comment: Yes. The simplest approach is to manually loop over the files. And IMHO it is also the most robust and maintainable and most efficient.

Comment: I know you have asked for a native way and you can find a relatively long example in MSDN but I'd recommend of using Boost. It is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: @OhadM: Where's boost's implementation of *delete all files except files in this list*? If that doesn't exist, then you have gained nothing. Plus, boost is anything but simple and straightforward. If anything, it's another constraint and dependency to worry about.

Comment: actually not, after you build boost you can find the full implementation in the cpp files. Also, no constraint or dependency,last time I have checked it's a wrapper. Not to mention it throws exceptions (in boost)..

Comment: @OhadM: Which CRT are you going to link your boost object-library against? Are you compiling the CRT statically into the object-library, or will this be linked dynamically? Answers to both of these questions will inevitably produce a dependency on a particular CRT, with implications on **client code**. Exposing an exception model at the interface makes matters worse, if anything.